# Mixed effects repeated measures - calculate individual level estimates of change

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, clinical-trials

Apologies if it feels that my question touches more on implementation difficulties as much as a true statistical query.

I have clinical trial data in long format

```
Subject    Timepoint    Clinical Score
 1            1             35
 1            2             20
 1            3             15
 2            1             38
 2            2             35
 2            3             30
```

I am attempting to replicate the methods of this paper (Levine and Leucht, 2016, Identifying a system of predominant negative symptoms: Network analysis of three randomized clinical trials, Scz Res) where the authors state: "To closely resemble the way change scores are computed in clinical trials, we computed estimated change scores (coded as improvement) for clinical scores with Mixed Models for Repeated Measures (MMRM), adjusting for baseline and treatment"

To this end I effectively want to calculate for each individual a number that I will be using as an estimate of change in clinical score.

I am working in R and have been using the nlme package.

A preliminary model (that I expect is incorrect) is:

```
model <- lme(clinical_score ~ time, random= ~time|subject_id, data=data, na.action =na.omit)
```

I would be most grateful for any advice regarding model construction, and where the individual level estimate of change is stored?

Many Thanks

Rob

Comment: If one treats a clinical trial with mixed effects as a hierarchical longitudinal model of growth then I would suggest Judith Singer's paper *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models, Hierarchical Models, and Individual Growth Models* (https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf). Despite a focus on education it may provide some direction. In addition her book with Willett *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* as well as the many other books on HLMs may be helpful, e.g., Raudenbush *HLMs*.

Comment: I think a potential model might be:

    model<- lme(panss ~ baseline + timepoint, random= ~timepoint|id, data=complete_melt, na.action =na.omit, method = "ML")      The individual level estimates would then be in model$coefficients